# Ubuntu 12.10 Update failed

Tags: updates, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Failed to download repository information

Check your Internet connection.

`W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found, 
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found, 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead`

My internet connection works well.
What are this updates and why it fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added the *Ubuntu-X team X Updates PPA* (`ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`) to your packages sources. This PPA doesn't contain any packages for Ubuntu 12.10.

Just remove it from your package sources. See "[How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)" if you don't know how to do this.